# How to create a new column based on conditions in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have 3 classes of students **A, B**, and **C**. My reproducible dataset looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(Student_ID =c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8),
                   Years_Attended = c(1991,1992,1995,1992,1993,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1993,1994,1995,1995,1993,1995,1990,1995,2000,1995,1996),
                   Class = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C"))
```

I want to add a new column (New Student) to my data frame using R. I define “New student” as any student who did not attend in the first year (i.e., minimum year) of any given class. My intended out put looks like this:

```
Intended_output <- data.frame(Student_ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8),
                              Years_Attended = c(1991,1992,1995,1992,1993,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1993,1994,1995,1995,1993,1995,1990,1995,2000,1995,1996),
                              Class = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C"),
                              New_Student = c("No","No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No","No","No","No","No","Yes","No","No","No","No","No","Yes","Yes"))
```

I have tried:

```
data$New_student <- ifelse(data$Years_Attended != min(data$Years_Attended, "Yes", "No"))
```

But I keep getting errors which I don't fully understand. I have been going in cycles for some time. I will really appreciate any pointers with this. The solution doesn't necessarily have to use the 'ifelse' statement. Any approach will certainly be appreciated.

Comment: The error is caused by a parentheses typo. It should be ```...!= min(data$Years_Attended), "Yes", "No")``` with a parentheses after the min call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `Class` find the minimum of the year add this as a new column to your dataset and for each Student check if they have attended that year.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Class) %>%
  summarise(min_year = min(Years_Attended)) %>%
  left_join(data, by = 'Class') %>%
  group_by(Class, Student_ID) %>%
  mutate(New_Student = if(any(Years_Attended == first(min_year)))'No' else 'Yes')

#  Class min_year Student_ID Years_Attended New_Student
#   <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>      
# 1 A         1991          1           1991 No         
# 2 A         1991          1           1992 No         
# 3 A         1991          1           1995 No         
# 4 A         1991          2           1992 Yes        
# 5 A         1991          2           1993 Yes        
# 6 A         1991          3           1991 No         
# 7 A         1991          3           1992 No         
# 8 A         1991          3           1993 No         
# 9 A         1991          3           1994 No         
#10 A         1991          3           1995 No         
# … with 11 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `data.table` approach:

```r
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(data)
dt[, New_Student := {
    class_min = min(Years_Attended)
    ave(Years_Attended, Student_ID, FUN = function(x) ifelse(class_min != min(x), 'Yes', 'No'))
    },
   by = Class]
```

This is actually a complicated question. We need to find the minimum year for each class and then, within each class, find out which students have a start year not equal to the minimum class year.

Comment: Thank you so much all for coming to my aid